# How to select all columns from a join table in vapor 4?

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

It seems that vapor add a new feature `eagerLoad` and remove `alsoDecode`. It is convenient for those which possessing parent-child or sibling relationships. But not for those without relationship.

I want to implement a tree structure whose nodes cannot be (or I don't know how to) involved in a relationship. Nodes have a parent and many children which are nodes too.

So I have three tables for this structure.

```
Tree:

| Field       | Type            |  
| ----------- | --------------- |  
| id          | UUID?           |  
| name        | String          |  
| nodes       | [Node]          |
| paths       | [Path]          |

Nodes:
| Field         | Type                       |  
| ------------- | -------------------------- |  
| id            | UUID?                      |  
| type          | NodeType(root, leaf, node) |    
| tree          | Tree                       |

Path:
| Field        | Type      |  
| ------------ | --------- |  
| id           | UUID?     |  
| distance     | Int       |  
| ancestorID   | UUID      |  
| descendantID | UUID      |  
| tree         | Tree      |
```

The question is
if I want to do

```sql
SELECT Nodes.id, Nodes.type, Path.ancestorID from Nodes
INNER JOIN Path
ON Nodes.id = Path.descendantID
```

How to write the codes.

Comment: With SwifQL it is easy: `SwifQL.select(\Nodes.$id, \Nodes.$type, \Path.$ancestorID).from(Nodes.table).join(.inner, Path.table, on: \Nodes.$id = \Path.$descendantID)`

Comment: @imike Thanks, it is a great way to solve it. But after conforming models to `Table`. It tells me that `Type 'Path' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`. Does it mean I should make major changes to my code? (like replace all @Filed with @Column).
(Btw, it takes me long to refetch package with SPM especially `swift-nio` )

Comment: If you want to stick to Fluent then you could use `SwifQLVapor` package and in this case you can use `@Field`. Other way is to switch to `Bridges` + `SwifQL` completely and then you should do major changes in your models, e.g. replace `@Field` with `@Column` and change all your queries to SwifQL. Second way have a lot of benefits from my point of view, but it may be not simple in the beginning. You could find me on Discord as iMike#3049 and I would love to help

Comment: @imike Thanks. This help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also choose to cast to `SQLDatabase`.
Make sure to import `SQLKit` too, a Fluent database can always be casted as SQLDatabase.

For example: `let sqlDb = req.db as? SQLDatabase` would give you the power to use custom queries like: `sqlDb?.select().from("Nodes").join("Path", on: "Nodes.id = Path.descendantId").all()`

For more info on SQLKit see: https://github.com/vapor/sql-kit

Reference: https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/fluent/advanced/ (Any Fluent Database can be cast to a SQLDatabase. This includes req.db, app.db, the database passed to Migration, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, and yes, you are right, I found it in the official documents later.
In addition to using `SwifQL`, there is also a native solution.
And I am using `.raw(..).all()` to get `rows`. Then using `decode` to decode rows to a `Codable` structure.